# My armature is not connected with bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I follow every Step which given in tutorial, but my armature is not connected with bone. After creating armature and bone, I tried to move my bone and armature in pose mode, but it's not working.

[image]

Comment: did you parent? select the object, then the bone, then ctrl P > With Automatic Weight

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the parent bones are set correctly

[image: Parent bones]